# Assigning Fortran variables to variables in module instance

Tags: module, fortran

I want to build a hash table module that can use different instances in Fortran 90 (I am not exactly sure what to name this).  This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
module hashing

  implicit none

  private
    real, dimension(:), allocatable                  :: &
      real1
  public                                             :: &
    Hash, hash_init, hash_push, hash_set, hash_get,     &
    hash_print

  type Hash
    character (len=128)                              :: &
      data_type
    integer                                          :: &
      array_size
  end type Hash
  contains

    subroutine hash_init (this)
      type(Hash), intent (in)                        :: &
        this

      if (trim(this%dtype) == "real1) then
        call make_real1(this%array_size)
      end if
    end subroutine hash_init

    subroutine hash_print (this)
      type(Hash), intent (in)                        :: &
        this

      if (trim(this%dtype) == "real1) then
        print *, real1
      end if
    end subroutine hash_print
end module hashing
```

So, in my test program, both `call hash_print` statements prints an array of size 5, because the real1 array is a general instance of module hashing, instead of (what I am trying to achieve) printing the first instance of size 10 and the second instance of size 5.

```
program test
  use hashing
  implicit none
  type(Hash)                                        :: &
      inst1, inst2


  inst1 = Hash("real1", 10)
  inst2 = Hash("real1", 5)
  call hash_init(inst1)
  call hash_init(inst2)

  call hash_print(inst1)
  call hash_print(inst2)

end program test
```

The main idea is to add integer and character type dimensions as well and using and expanding on the if statements, but I need to know where in the module I need to declare these allocatable dimensions so that they are bound to a specific instance only.  If possible!  I've tried declaring the allocatable array inside the `hash_init` subroutine, but then it is not available for the `hash_print` subroutine.

Comment: Do you really want to limit yourself to the old Fortran 90? Is it important for the answers to stick to that? Allocatable derived type components are not allowed in Fortran 90 nor are allocatable strings.

Comment: Could you please make more obvious what is the question? Have you tried to look at generic hash table implementations available on the web?

Comment: @VladimirF I am using only Fortran90 for work.  My question is (in the case of the question):  I want two instances of the real1 dimension at the same time (one being assigned to inst1 with size 10 and another assigned to inst2 with size 5).  I guess I want something similar to python class instances.

Comment: Since you've tagged your question with an oop tag I have to say that using module variables is not exactly an oop way to do things - you should wrap them into a type as well. In this case you will only need to hold the instance of your holder type in your program and you do not need to declare any public module variables - that's considered unsafe from OOP perspective.

Comment: I really suggest allowing at least Fortran 95, better modern 2003/2008 for anything with objects/instances and so on. If you want `real1` to be inside the derived type, you need Fortran 2003. But I still don't understand the question, but that can be my fault.

Comment: Thanks for the comments/suggestions.  I will look into f95 and I've removed the oop tag.

Comment: Which compiler (version) do you use / need to support?